# How to change the location where source files of newly added classes are created in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Whenever I add a new class to a visual studio project, the source files are created in the same directory where the .vcproj file of the project is located. Is there a way to change this location? for an example, create the files in a sub directory located in that directory?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder, and add to project by right clicking on the folder and selecting Add New Item.

Comment: FYI this makes the namespace of the file "<project>.<folder>".  It seems MS's intention was for folders to reflect your namespace structure.

Answer (score 1):

create a folder(s) in your project within visual studio?

Comment: on the right click menu of the project select 'Add->New FOlder'. Then right click the folder and use its add menu to creatre new files. You can also drag and drop files between folders within the IDE (for re-organising existing projects)